# Node js server working when run on windows but in linux get TypeError

Tags: node.js, linux, windows, websocket

I am running a node js server that uses websockets, and when I run it on windows everything works perfectly. it creates the websockets, sends messages pulls up the page.

however, I transferred my code to a linux machine exactly as it was on Windows when it was working, and I get the following error -

```
Client websocket connected!
fs.js:297
    binding.open(pathModule_makeLong(path),

TypeError: path must be a string or Buffer
```

this is happening in my bindCallback function I am calling from this line -

```
// Create the server object
var server = http.createServer(serverCallback);
// Setup the server to listen
server.listen(8080, bindCallback);
```

inside the bind callback function I have this -

```
var bindCallback = function () {
    websocket_server.on('connection', function (client_socket) {
        console.log("Client websocket connected!");

        client_socket.on('message', function (message) {
            console.log("Received websocket greeting!: " + message);
        });

        acceptCallback(client_socket);
   });
};
```

and according to the console output, the TypeError:path must be a string or Buffer error is occuring at the line that says -

```
acceptCallback(client_socket);
```

the complete error output looks like this -

```
fs.js:297
  binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path),
      ^

TypeError: path must be a string or Buffer
    at Object.fs.readFile (fs.js:297:11)
    at acceptCallback (/home/pi/veud/nodejs/main.js:346:8)
    at WebSocketServer.<anonymous> (/home/pi/veud/nodejs/main.js:397:9)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at WebSocketServer.emit (events.js:194:7)
    at handleUpgrade (/home/pi/veud/nodejs/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocketServer.js:88:16)
    at WebSocketServer.completeUpgrade (/home/pi/veud/nodejs/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocketServer.js:270:5)
    at WebSocketServer.handleUpgrade (/home/pi/veud/nodejs/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocketServer.js:197:10)
    at Server.WebSocketServer._ultron.on (/home/pi/veud/nodejs/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocketServer.js:87:14)
    at emitThree (events.js:116:13)
```

any idea on why this error might be occurring only in Linux and not in windows and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you ever print the value of _makeLong to your screen ?

Comment: whats weird is i don't have a variable I have made named  _makeLong, must be something internal.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of path parameter that you are passing. Windows path is not case sensitive but in case of linux, path is case sensitive. There are more difference related to back slash and forward slash. These difference could create problem. You can read this article which talk about differences in path between windows and linux - ***https://www.howtogeek.com/137096/6-ways-the-linux-file-system-is-different-from-the-windows-file-system/***

Comment: Okay thanks I will try to look into that, but if you  look at the code I passed into acceptCallback the variable passed into that is client_socket which is a variable representing a clients socket that should be automatically created when a client connects to the server, I didnt actually give it a path myself its a variable object representing clients when a websocket connection is established with them.